# Symfony2 render controller from service?

Tags: symfony

I want to render controller from my custom class. I know that I should use forward function but I don't know with service I have to use?

I have found something like that

```
$subRequest = $this->container->get('request')->duplicate(
array(), 
null, 
array('topicId' => $topicId,'_controller' => 'SomeBundle:Topic:close'));

return $this->container->get('http_kernel')
    ->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
```

It's a forward function but if I use it I get headers.

How to hide header from forward function?

I need it because I want to render custom logic ( get from DB and other ). It's my idea for modules.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a post about controller utils on [whitewashing.de](http://www.whitewashing.de/2013/06/27/extending_symfony2__controller_utilities.html)
I created my own utils function I inject in every controller.

The forward function in there works fine up to sf 2.7 and looks like this:

```
/**
 * Forwards the request to another controller.
 *
 * @param string $controller The controller name (a string like BlogBundle:Post:index)
 * @param array  $path       An array of path parameters
 * @param array  $query      An array of query parameters
 *
 * @return Response A Response instance
 */
public function forward($controller, array $path = array(), array $query = array())
{
    $path['_controller'] = $controller;
    $subRequest = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest()->duplicate($query, null, $path);

    return $this->container->get('http_kernel')->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for [forwarding requests](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding-to-another-controller).